# Raspberry Pi camera mmal Error

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspistill

Recently I use my Picamera. When I run

```
sudo raspistill -o myImage.jpg
```

I get the following error

> mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
>   mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
>   mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
>   mmal: Failed to create camera component
>   mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
>   mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly

So I enabled Picamera but it doesn't works.
How should I do?

Comment: Please update your answer and explain very carefully what steps you tried to install the camera module

Comment: Firsttime, I used 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade'

Comment: Next, I updated firmware and checked the camera module

Comment: Please update the question itself with these details.